# Retrieve streaming response body with additional data

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I have an API which responds with:

```
  @PostMapping
  public StreamingResponseBody export(<variables>) {
    return outputStream -> method(variables);
  }
```

Export service (which contains this API), does not have any data source attached - it is a simple microservice.
Variables mostly are: really big JSON file with additional flags.

Problem is, that the method at the export also extracts additional data `List<Object> data`, required for further processing.

How to pass `StreamingResponseBody` together with `data` ?
Any other out of the box solution would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have went with an ObjectOutputStream implementation. I have created:

```
public class Response implements Serializable {
  private byte[] document;
  private List<Object> data;
}
```

and method just:

```
public void method(OutputStream os) throws Exception {
   try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
     oos.writeObject(buildObj());
   }
}
```